# Disabled a select option based on days using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two datepicker for get days of difference between current date and to date.
I need that days are come when current date and to date selected then dropdown value will be disabled based on days.

**Suppose**

1) 6 days are come then all options will be disabled and

2) When 7 days are come then all options are disabled except 1 week and

3) when 14 days are all options are disabled except 1 week and 15 days.

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
  });

$('.todate').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
  });

$('.fromdate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
var minValue = $(this).val();
minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
$('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
calculate();
  });

$('.todate').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
var maxValue = $(this).val();
maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
$('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
calculate();
   });

function calculate() {
var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
var diff = 0;
if (d1 && d2) {

  diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/(oneDay)));
}
var days = $('.calculated').val(diff);
if(days < 7){
$("select option:contains('1')").attr("disabled",true);
   }
   }

<input class='fromdate' /><br><br>
<input class='todate' /><br><br>
<input class='calculated' /><br><br>

<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-info btn-round" data-size="7" tabindex="-98">
      <option value="1">1 week </option>
      <option value="2">15 days</option>
      <option value="3">1 month</option>
      <option value="4">2 month</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k6nvcr4f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function calculate() {
  var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
  var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
  var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
  var diff = 0;
  if (d1 && d2) {

    diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/(oneDay)));
  }
  var days = $('.calculated').val(diff);
  $(".selectpicker option").attr("disabled","disabled");

  if (diff >= 7) {
       $(".selectpicker option:contains('1 week')").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  if (diff >= 14) {
       $(".selectpicker option:contains('15 days')").removeAttr("disabled");
  }     

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1Lg1rz1/

Comment: Thank you for helping but I have issue that select option are not disabled in my broswer and I also check it in fiddle its working perfectly what I need

Comment: I fixed it.  I removed the onblur attribute and put on change in the javascript and changed the order or the input elements.  https://jsfiddle.net/seoy10bp/2/

Comment: Its working fine on fiddle but in my browser its not working and also i cannot get days value in alert

Comment: When I removed onblur attribute then function is not working and also i cannot get days value in alert

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet of what I'll do:
(See the few comments in the JS code)

```js
$('.fromdate, .todate').datepicker({ // Merged selector
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
});

$('.fromdate').datepicker().bind("change", function() {
  var minValue = $(this).val();
  minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
  $('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
  calculate();
});

$('.todate').datepicker().bind("change", function() {
  var maxValue = $(this).val();
  maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
  $('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
  calculate();
});

function calculate() {
  var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
  var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var diff = 0;
  if (d1 && d2)
    diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
  var days = $('.calculated').val(diff);

  // Disable all
  $(".selectpicker option").attr("disabled", true);
  // Re-enable one-by-one according to duration betwen the two dates
  if (diff >= 7)  $(".selectpicker option[value=1]").removeAttr("disabled");
  if (diff >= 14) $(".selectpicker option[value=2]").removeAttr("disabled");
  if (diff >= 28) $(".selectpicker option[value=3]").removeAttr("disabled");
  if (diff >= 56) $(".selectpicker option[value=4]").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<input class='fromdate' /><br><br>
<input class='todate' /><br><br>
<input class='calculated' /><br><br>

<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-info btn-round" data-size="7" tabindex="-98">
  <option value="1">1 week </option>
  <option value="2">15 days</option>
  <option value="3">1 month</option>
  <option value="4">2 month</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for helping but I have issue that select option are not disabled in my broswer and I also check it in fiddle its working perfectly what I need

Comment: @Arslan What do you mean by "fix" ?

Comment: In my fiddle code working is not a good way Please can you fix error using this fiddle?

Comment: yes like this one and I have change my code in fiddle there is some errors can you fix it using this link? https://jsfiddle.net/k6nvcr4f/6/

Comment: Are you fixing it?